# change event with arrow keys in select elements

Tags: jquery, html

In a select element ( a combo ) the change event is execute when the element lose the focus, is possible execute the change event when a combo change with a arrow key ?

I try a live in all combos :

```
$('select').live('keyup',function(e) {
  if ([33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1)
  {                 
        ///obj.blur();
        obj.change();
        ///obj.focus();     
  }
});
```

With firefox works,but in chromium launch two changes with arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

You're firing both the `change` event and the `keyup` event when using the keys to alter the `select` value, and since the `keyup` event triggers the `change` event, that event is fired twice, once from the original change of the `select` element, and once from the triggering of `change` in the `keyup` event.

To avoid firing it twice you could check for the events `originalEvent` or something similar, but the easy solution is to just use a flag that stays on just long enough to not execute the same stuff twice:

```
var flag=true;

$('select').on({
    keyup: function(e){
        flag=false;
        if ([33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.which) !=-1) $(this).trigger('change');
        setTimeout(function() {flag=true}, 200);
    },
    change: function(e) {
        if (flag) {
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

Be aware that `Array.indexOf()` is not cross browser!